# Prove that the sequence $(1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!})$ is cauchy?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, cauchy-sequences

> Prove that the sequence $x_n=1+\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{1}{n!}$ is cauchy?

Here is my attempt and I used this [How to prove that $x_n=1+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}$ is a Cauchy sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/455997/842235) and complete my proof.

Let  $\varepsilon>0$ and $n>m>N(\varepsilon)>\max\{4,2+log_2(\frac{1}{\varepsilon})\}$. Consider,

$$ |x_n-x_m|=\bigg|\frac{1}{(m+1)!}+\frac{1}{(m+2)!}+...+\frac{1}{n!} \bigg|$$

Since $2^n<n!$ for $n\geq 4$,

$$ |x_n-x_m|=\bigg|\frac{1}{(m+1)!}+\frac{1}{(m+2)!}+...+\frac{1}{n!} \bigg|<\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{m+2}}+...\frac{1}{2^{n}}$$

$$ |x_n-x_m|=\bigg|\frac{1}{(m+1)!}+\frac{1}{(m+2)!}+...+\frac{1}{n!} \bigg|<\frac{1}{2^{m+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{m+2}}+...\frac{1}{2^{n}}<\sum_{k>m}\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{1}{2^{m-2}}<\varepsilon$$

whenever $m>N(\varepsilon)>\max\{4,2+log_2(\frac{1}{\varepsilon})\}$

That is for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N(\varepsilon) \in N$ such that $|x_n-x_m| <\varepsilon$ whenever $n>m>N(\varepsilon)>\max\{4,2+log_2(\frac{1}{\varepsilon})\}$

Can anyone verify my attempt?

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: @QC_QAOA Are there any mistakes?

Comment: No, no mistakes that could ruin the message. I guess a nitpick might be you say $N(\epsilon)\in\mathbb{N}$ when it might not be but that's very minor

Comment: @QC_QAOA Oh that $\mathbb{N}$ thank you very much